# Creating abstract class with 'where' constraint that also implements interfaces

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to make a `abstract ObservableCollection` class which requires its members to implement an interface `IXMLEntity` I also want the abstract class to implement this interface also -- the reasoning is that the Collection could then be XMLSerialized, and include all its children.

```
public abstract class BaseCollectionModel<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    where T : IXMLEntity
{

}
```

How should I do this? I am just starting a new library for my project so any other design patterns are up for suggestions.

I plan on making BaseCollectionModel a class which is able to provide 'infinite scrolling' by making service calls for more items as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the usual way?

```
public abstract class BaseCollectionModel<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IXMLEntity
where T : IXMLEntity
{

}
```

Comment: Ah shoot, Had the ordering incorrect! Tried so many things, guess I missed that part ;p

Comment: I do that all the time too. :>

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public abstract class BaseCollectionModel<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IXMLEntity
    where T : IXMLEntity
{

}
```

Comment: Ah shoot, Had the ordering incorrect! Tried so many things, guess I missed that part ;p